# data migration query

Tags: php, mysql, database-migration

I have searched many questions and ready many different articles about this but no one seems to help me out or may be I could not able to understand completely.  I want to migrate data from one database to another database.
This is my query

```
$query = mysql_query("
    Insert into database2.table2 (id, data)
    select (id, name) from database1.table1
");
if($query == false){   
    die(mysql_error());   
}
```

When I execute this query it shows me this error message which is really annoying *Operand should contain 1 column(s)*

I searched about it but found nothing which could help me.

**Note:** This query is initally for my test case. Actual query will be made later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query (Removing parenthesis from select fields),

```
INSERT into database2.table2 (id, data) SELECT id, name from database1.table1
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Ohh! Thanks Rikesh, I didn't notice that I am using brackets with SELECT.

Comment: @HoNeY - Glad to help you. Please don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.

Comment: What if the data is too large? Can this query handle large database too?

Comment: this is the best answer, better than mine, because it has links to PDO tutorials :)

Answer (score 0):

remove the parenthesis from

```
select (id, name)
```

to

```
select id, name
```

final result:

```
$query = mysql_query("Insert into database2.table2 (id, data) select id, name from database1.table1");
```

Comment: Really appreciating your answer. Thanks but I have ticked one more question that will this query slow down my pc if the data is large?